# Two methods of solving the differential equation $y' = .75 -.005y$

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I am working on a differential equation problem and I am stumped since two different methods seem to give me two different answers

#### Method 1

Given $\frac{dy}{dx}  = .75 -.005y$

$$\frac{dy}{.75-.005y} = dx$$

Integrating both sides

$$-200 \ln(.75-.005y) = t + c$$

#### Method 2

Given $\frac{dy}{dx}  = .75 -.005y$

$$\frac{dy}{dx}  =  \frac{150 - y}{200} \implies \frac{dy}{150-y}  =  \frac{dt}{200}$$

$$-\ln(150-y) =  \frac{t+c}{200}$$

$$-200\ln(150-y) = t+c$$

Can someone explain why one method does not work
Thanks

Comment: Add $-200\ln(200)$ to both sides of your solution in first method and simplify. For the right hand side, see that $c$ is as arbitrary a constant as $c-200\ln(200)$

Comment: I think you want an x in place of t on the right side of both answers.

Comment: hint $150-y = 200(.75-0.005y)$. remember the product rule for logarithms?

Comment: Thanks! For future viewers the integration constant(c) can be any value so ignoring the constant both methods work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are the same up to an arbitrary constant of integration.

HINT: $$\log a - c = \log a - \log e^c = \log \frac{a}{e^c}.$$